# Error 400 bad request on live website but not on my production build

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I currently have a live website up and running. However, i get a `GET http://example.com/api/global_rankings 400 (Bad Request)`
its a 400 error so im assuming its from the client side.

```
 getGlobalRankings(){
        var request = new Request('/api/global_rankings', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' })
        });
        fetch(request).then((response) => {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                this.setRankings(data);
            });
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

server.js

```
let pool = new pg.Pool({
    port: 5432,
    database: 'boost',
    max: 20,
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
});
app.get('/api/global_rankings', function(request, response){
    pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
        if(err){
            return response.status(400).send(err);
        }
        else{
            db.query("SELECT * FROM myquery", function(err, table){
                done();
                if(err){
                    return response.status(400).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    response.status(201).send({value: table.rows});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
});
```

I dont know where to start to fix this problem. 
Am i suppose to do something like `new Request('mydomain/api/global_rankings');`?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a different configuration file for API calls which contains host, port and listed suffix for each endpoint. Concatenate them wherever require.

dev.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'8000'
    endPoint1:'/api/doSmething'
}
```

prod.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    host:'https://remotehost.com',
    port:'80'
    endPoint1:'/api/doSmething'
}
```

node server :

```
app.get(config.endPoint1, function(request, response){...
```

front end :

```
var request = new Request(config.host +':'+ config.port + config.endPoint1, {...
```